# core dumped when copying a string to first element of the pair

Tags: c++, string, std-pair

I have a list of pairs: list<pair<string, list>> and i also have a string A and an iterator for the list named ti
When I try to copy A to (*ti).first by writing a code (*ti).first += A or (*ti).first = A or strcpy((*ti).first, A) I always get the error "core dumped". I have also tried to allocate the memory for (*ti).first by using (*ti).first = (char)malloc(sizeof(A)) but nothing helped

I tried memory allocation for the first element of the pair, I tried copying the string in different ways such as strcat, strcpy, +=, =.

Comment: Please show a [mre] rather than describing your code

Comment: Works on my machine.  Turn on compiler warnings.  Fix the warnings.  Turn on sanitizers.  Fix the problems from the sanitizers.  Does that fix it on your machine?